# Works On MariaDB But Not In MySQL : ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have this table and SQL syntax :

[image]

```
INSERT INTO robo_pathfinder (date, robo, timestamp, seq, max_seq, symbol, base, quote, action, qty, price, pay, pay_coin, get, get_coin, position)
VALUES ('2020-08-26 05:33:42', '0', '1598394823856', '3', '3', 'XRPUSDT', 'XRP', 'USDT', 'SELL', '36.3', '0.27814', '36.3', 'XRP', '10.08638552', 'USDT', '')
```

and I keep getting this error message :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'get, get_coin, position)
VALUES ('2020-08-26 05:33:42', '0', '1598394823856', '3' at line 1
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7.31

That syntax works fine on MariaDB. But why doesn't work on MySQL?

Comment: `GET` is a reserved word.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-G

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**